# How to sort Panda table according to another Panda table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The following question appeared during my last round of my interview and unfortunately i couldn't do it.
I have the first table as:

```
ticker            AAPL       MSFT        WMT
date                                        
2015-12-31  101.696810  52.829107  58.379766
2016-01-04  101.783763  52.181598  58.532144
2016-01-05   99.233131  52.419653  59.922592
2016-01-06   97.291172  51.467434  60.522580
2016-01-07   93.185040  49.677262  61.932075
```

```
data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'WMT'], 
                        qopts = { 'columns': ['ticker', 'date', 'adj_close'] }, 
                        date = { 'gte': '2015-12-31', 'lte': '2016-12-31' }, 
                        paginate=True)

data = data.set_index('date')
data = data.pivot (columns='ticker')
```

now I want to get 10 day rolling standard deviation from the above table. 
we get:

```
ticker          AAPL      MSFT       WMT
date                                    
2016-01-14  3.128565  1.303180  1.144040
2016-01-15  2.750341  1.272089  1.058815
2016-01-19  2.003544  1.282124  0.928272
2016-01-20  1.496574  1.048227  1.177348
2016-01-21  1.261271  0.911893  1.209570
```

now I want to sort the above volatility table by their volatility for instance on 2016-01-14 - 2016-01-15 we should have the following: ( how do we best sort this table by the row?)

```
1.144040    1.303180     3.128565
1.058815    1.272089     2.750341
```

now how do we sort the original table 'data' by the position of above volatility table ? for instance on 2016-01-14 - 2016-01-15, the table should be:

```
58.379766    52.829107   101.696810 
58.532144    52.181598   101.783763
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original dataframe and the volatility dataframe have different indexes, but you say you want to sort original `df` by the position of volatility table. Therefore, it only makes sense that you want the result in the format of the underlying numpy ndarrays of these 2 dataframes. Assume original dataframe is named `org_df` and volatility table is `df`. Using numpy `argsort` and fancy indexing to achieve it.

```
import numpy as np

a = org_df.to_numpy()
b = df.to_numpy()
y_b = np.argsort(b, axis=1)
x_b = np.arange(b.shape[0])[:,None]

volatility_sorted = b[x_b, y_b]

print(volatility_sorted)

Out[39]:
array([[1.14404 , 1.30318 , 3.128565],
       [1.058815, 1.272089, 2.750341],
       [0.928272, 1.282124, 2.003544],
       [1.048227, 1.177348, 1.496574],
       [0.911893, 1.20957 , 1.261271]])

org_df_sorted = a[x_b, y_b]

print(org_df_sorted )

Out[49]:
array([[ 58.379766,  52.829107, 101.69681 ],
       [ 58.532144,  52.181598, 101.783763],
       [ 59.922592,  52.419653,  99.233131],
       [ 51.467434,  60.52258 ,  97.291172],
       [ 49.677262,  61.932075,  93.18504 ]])
```

---

Explain

On, `x_b = np.arange(b.shape[0])[:,None]`

It creates 2-d array with the shape `(5, 1)` where `5` is the length of axis=0 of `b`. Its output is

```
Out[161]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Numpy fancy indexing needs array indexes on both axis 0 and 1. The required output is 2-d, so these array indexes must be 2-d arrays. This command creates array index for axis 0 to use with numpy fancy indexing. `b.shape[0]` returns lenghth of b's axis=0. `np.arange(b.shape[0])` returns 1-d array which has shape `(5,)`. We need to upscale it to 2-d, so adding `[:,None]` (or you may use `np.newaxis` instead of `None`) is the short way to add one more dimension to it. The long way is using `np.reshape`

On, `y_b = np.argsort(b, axis=1)`

It sorts `b` by axis 1 (the right-most axis). `argsort` returns the position/index of the sorted order instead of the sorted values. Therefore, we may use it to sort both `a` and `b`.

On, `volatility_sorted = b[x_b, y_b]`

`b[x_b, y_b]` is fancy indexing on `b` using array index `x_b` on axis=0 and `y_b` on axis=1. Jake has a great book on Python Data Science. He explains very well on fancy indexing [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html). If you want to go deep in detail, check numpy docs on indexing [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: Thank you very much @Andy L. This is the answer that was required by the interviewer. However, could you please explain the following two lines of code ? I googled and looked at the API documents but it's still not very clear to me.
x_b = np.arange(b.shape[0])[:,None]
volatility_sorted = b[x_b, y_b]

Comment: Thank you Andy for the explanation. I will take a look at the book.